# Json schema not validating/working with sub schema

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have json shown below. I want to get it work against a list of zoo which will must have zoo_unique_code. But can have animal or bird or both or none of them. But i want to validate it with sub schema if it have animal or bird e.g bird/animal_id. It seems subschema is not working.

```
{
"type": "object",
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"definitions": {
    "animal_id": {
        "type": "string",
        "maxLength": 24
    },
    "bird_id": {
        "type": "string",
        "maxLength": 50
    },
    "zoo_bird_and_animal": {
        "type": "object",
        "anyOf": [{
                "properties": {
                    "zoo_bird": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "required": [
                            "zoo_bird_id"
                        ],
                        "properties": {
                            "zoo_bird_id": {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/bird_id"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "properties": {
                    "zoo_animal": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "required": [
                            "zoo_animal_id"
                        ],
                        "properties": {
                            "zoo_animal_id": {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/animal_id"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"properties": {
    "zoo_list": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 1,
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
                "zoo_unique_code"
            ],
            "minProperties": 1,
            "properties": {
                "zoo_unique_code": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "NEWYORKZOO",
                        "PARISZOO"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "$ref": "#/definitions/zoo_bird_and_animal"
        }
    }
}
}
```

And testing it with

```
{
   "zoo_list": [
    {
     "zoo_unique_code": "NEWYORKCODE",
        "zoo_bird": {
            "zoo_bird_id": "newid"
        }
    }
   ]
}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add a data example also? Great would be a shared link from https://jsonschema.dev/
also please describe what is not working in the subschema

Comment: Can you please provide your instance data you expect to be valid and invalid?

Comment: (Please note that https://jsonschema.dev currently only supports draft-07)

Comment: Edited description. Can you please see it again.

Comment: in the `anyOf` you got a `"$ref": "#/definitions/zoo_animal_id"` which seems to be not-existing, maybe you wanted to use the `#/definitions/animal_id` here

Comment: @MichaelB. apologies fro that. corrected again.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can interpret your schema, it seems you want to use a combining schema at the end, rather then having the `ref` in the same items part.

With this `allOf` the schema needs to be a valid object like defined in `items` and like the `ref` in the `definitions`

Also the other error comes from using `anyOf` instead of `allOf`.

With `anyOf`, it needs to be valid against either the first or the second of the schemas, as both validate against a object, even when the first is invalid, the second is valid, so everything is valid. This could also be changed with `additionalProperties`, but then it does not work the way you nested it.

> `anyOf`: As long as a value validates against either of these schemas, it is considered valid against the entire combined schema.
>   - [combining-schemas](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#combining-schemas)

You would also want to use `allOf` here, so it must validate against all, or rewrite this condition to not use an object here.

With that `anyOf` to `allOf` modification, your given data now also validates the `bird_id`:

And i think you are not using `draft-04` here, looks like `draft-7`.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "animal_id": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 24
    },
    "bird_id": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 50
    },
    "zoo_bird_and_animal": {
      "type": "object",
      "allOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "zoo_bird": {
              "type": "object",
              "required": [
                "zoo_bird_id"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "zoo_bird_id": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/bird_id"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "zoo_animal": {
              "type": "object",
              "required": [
                "zoo_animal_id"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "zoo_animal_id": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/animal_id"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "zoo_list": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "zoo_unique_code"
            ],
            "minProperties": 1,
            "properties": {
              "zoo_unique_code": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "NEWYORKZOO",
                  "PARISZOO"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/zoo_bird_and_animal"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Invalid data, see: [invalid](https://jsonschema.dev/s/7cZ9L):

```
{
  "zoo_list": [
    {
      "zoo_unique_code": "NEWYORKCODE",
      "zoo_bird": {
        "zoo_bird_id": "newidnewidnewidnewidnewidnewidnewnewidnewidnewidnewidnewidnewidnew"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Valid data, see [valid](https://jsonschema.dev/s/KvpKt):

```
{
  "zoo_list": [
    {
      "zoo_unique_code": "NEWYORKZOO",
      "zoo_bird": {
        "zoo_bird_id": "newid"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. sorry to say this but problem is still there. If i give "zoo_bird_id": ""  inside zoo_list (skipping rest of code here because of comment section). Schema is not validating "zoo_bird_id".